# Using a pointer to struct returned from a function

Tags: c, function, struct, casting, return-value

I have a function which clones members of a struct and returns a struct (NOT pointer). This newly created object is short lived.

```c
struct my_struct {
   int a;
   int b;
};

inline struct my_struct my_struct_clone(struct my_struct src, int members){
   struct my_struct copy = {0};
   //... Do copy based on args
   return copy;
}
```

I cannot return a pointer as it would be pointing to deallocated memory. How can I pass the return value of the clone function as a pointer to a second function? Similar to the following, but without using an intermediate placeholder.

```c
void do_sth(struct my_struct const *p);

struct my_struct val = my_struct_clone(&other, 123);
do_sth(&val);
```

The following fails (lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand):

```c
do_sth(&(my_struct_clone(&other, 123)));
```

But it is possible to declare a struct inline

```
do_sth(&(struct my_struct){.a = 1, .b = 2});
```

To address some of the comments about using an intermediate. The question is about avoiding the creation of one, and not "I can't use one because...". I recently encountered a coding construct where I thought I could but discovered I couldn't, hence the question. Also, passing in an already allocated instance to the clone function still requires an intermediate. I would prefer to not clutter the function header with variable declarations that are short lived like this.

Comment: Is the placeholder a problem?

Comment: I don't like answering with "Why do you want do A? Do B instead!".... BUT... why don't implement your `my_struct_clone()` providing a pointer of a newly allocated struct? Of course you will have to design your program freeing the memory outside the function, but it will prevent you from making strange attempts.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use an intermediate placeholder? Too readable? Too maintainable?

Comment: @Lundin I didn't say "can't use" I asked if there is a way "to avoid". Was thinking maybe there was some compiler trickery I could use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value returned by the function is an [*rvalue*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category#Non-lvalue_object_expressions), 
which means that its address can't be taken.

But [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) are [*lvalues*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category#Lvalue_expressions) which means their address *can* be taken.

You need the temporary variable to be able to pass the result of the cloning function as a pointer.

Comment: I'm going to guess a smart compiler would optimize away the declaration (and accompanying stack allocation).

Answer (score 1):

I would personnaly do something like:

```
inline void my_struct_clone(const struct my_struct src, struct my_struct *srcCopy, int members){
   //... Do copy based on args
   srcCopy->a = src.a;
   srcCopy->b = src.b;
}
```

So you would call and declare the clone as such:

```
struct my_struct strClone;
my_struct_clone(str, &strClone, 123);
do_sth(strClone); // Call to strClone
```

Comment: It still requires the use of an intermediate, which I'm trying to avoid. Also the function is now not really a `clone` but an `init` (schemantics).